# FormControl always invalid with data in form

Tags: angular, frontend, ngx-editor

I create this form and I have some fields where the values are in variables.

```
 this.commentForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: [null, Validators.required],
      description: [null, Validators.required],
      textId: [this.data.textId, Validators.required],
      userId: [this.userService.getUserLoggedId, Validators.required],
      likes: [this.rating, Validators.required],
      isActive: [true],
    })
```

When I'll send for API exists one verification:

```
if(this.commentForm.invalid) {
      this.notification.error("Required Fields!")
      return
}
```

If I make a console.log(this.commentForm.value) it's possible to see the values

```
{
    "title": "test",
    "description": "fsfsdfswe",
    "textId": "86f454d6",
    "userId": "8369ce3c",
    "likes": 4,
    "isActive": true
}
```

But the status it's always INVALID and I cant send it to the backend if the status is invalid.
I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: You have not posted enough code.

Comment: write: `console.log(this.commentForm.value,this.commentForm.invalid)`. the status should be valid :(. I imagine the error is not here.

Answer (score -1):

add validators to "isActive" in your TS file